# Suppose I want to compete with graphics API companies like opengl or DirectX. What I have to do?

Tags: graphics, gpu, low-level

Obviously I am not going to create a company that will compete with giant companies like the ones I mentioned above. But for learning purpose and curiosity let's suppose that I've created one!

I did a Google search before asking and went to several sites, which left me even more confused. You haven't direct acess to the graphics card, the operating system don't let you acess registers of gpu, and etc. (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So what kind of magic did these guys do? What language did they use? How does opengl of Khronos Group have access to the video card? Is it the operating system that does not allow the direct access of graphic card, or the graphic card itself?

Comment: Read [What are Graphics Drivers?](https://help.sketchup.com/en/sketchup/what-graphics-card-and-graphics-driver).

Comment: Khronos standardizes the API.  The graphics drivers *implement* / *follow* that standard, to let programs draw using OpenGL (or Vulkan), using OpenGL as the language for communicating with the graphics drivers.  (This would be an answer to your question if it didn't have such a weird title, but for now it's just a comment.)

Comment: Thanks Rabbid76 and Peter Corders! Many of my doubts have been clarified. So the graphics API is not something that a programmer can create without a graphics driver that implements it! The title was a little strange because there were similar questions but with answers that did not satisfy, they just mentioned the shaders that went to the graphics card.